# Kotlin: receiving elements in different coroutine is not working properly

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I've below kotlin coroutine code.

```
    import kotlinx.coroutines.*
    import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.*

    fun main() = runBlocking <Unit> {
        val channel = Channel<Int>(4)
        val sender = launch (coroutineContext) {
            repeat(10) {
                println("sending $it")
                channel.send(it)
                delay(100)
            }
        }

        delay(1000)

        //launch {  for (y in channel) println("receiving $y") }

        for (y in channel) println("receiving $y")
    }
```

It works fine. If I put the logic to receive elements from channel into another coroutine(i.e., put `for` inside `launch` as in commented code), then it gets struck at below output(i.e., I'm expecting sending and receiving till 10 but it gets stuck at `receiving 3`).

```
    sending 0
    sending 1
    sending 2
    sending 3
    sending 4
    receiving 0
    receiving 1
    receiving 2
    receiving 3
```

How to receive elements in another coroutine without any glitches?

I'm using version `compile("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.1.1")`

Comment: If by "another coroutine" you mean the commented-out line with `launch`, I can share that it works correctly on my machine. Kotlin 1.3.21, coroutines-core 1.1.1.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - I have updated the question. Please read and let me know if its't make sense.

Comment: OK, so you confirmed you meant how I understood it. It works here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that your channel is not closed, so your `for-each` loop may never end. If you close your channel after the `repeat` block, you the code will be finished gracefully:

import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.*

```
fun main() = runBlocking <Unit> {
    val channel = Channel<Int>(4)
    val sender = launch (coroutineContext) {
        repeat(10) {
            println("sending $it")
            channel.send(it)
            delay(100)
        }
        channel.close()
    }

    delay(1000)

    launch {  for (y in channel) println("receiving $y") }

}
```